# InfoPath Calculated Date

Tags: 2010, infopath, date-time

I am trying to have the `Calculated Date` field be the first of the month, the month before `Start Date`. This works when the `Calculated Date` month is double digit but breaks on single digit months. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
concat(substring(StartDate[ID = Availability], 1, 4), "-", string(number(substring(StartDate[ID = Availability], 6, 2)) - 1), "-01T00:00:00")
```

[image: Example Dates]

EDIT: Corrected Screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by modifying my code to:

```
concat(substring(StartDate[ID = Availability], 1, 4), "-", (concat(substring("00", 1, 2 - string-length(substring(StartDate[ID = Availability], 6, 2) - 1)), (substring(StartDate[ID = Availability], 6, 2)) - 1)), "-01T00:00:00")
```